# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Cairo.Context' to `Cairo.Context' - mono version conflict

Tags: c#, mono, cairo

So apparently, I'm having conflicting versions of Mono.Cairo. I can see that in /usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Cairo there are two folders, one for version 2.0 and one from version 4.0 . From what I read on google results, this is causing a conflict. The line of code that's causing trouble is `using (Cairo.Context ctx = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create (area.GdkWindow))`

Apparently, this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672771/mono-ubuntu-conflicting-definitions), but I have no idea what they're saying. So I put it to you: is there a way to get dmcs to use non-conflicting Cairo.Context?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with xmonad, with the newest version pf the package mono-complete from apt-get.

To compile í write: `dmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp -pkg:mono-cairo Teikniforrit.cs`, Teikniforrit.cs being a simple painting tool. mcs and gmcs have never worked for me. I set up mono on Windows 7 to see how that worked and it works fine with gmcs, but not mcs or dmcs.

Comment: Where is `Gdk.CairoHelper` declared, and have you checked which reference you're using for *that* assembly? How are you building, exactly?

Comment: Is your project a 3.5 .net or 4.0 .net usually you can correct this by 1 of two things, deprecate the version build to 3.5 recompile then promote to 4.0 or you will have to reference the assembly by `Aliasing` bacically using `newCairor = Caiaro ` give it a unique name in your using clause

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that you're being hit by the same [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10484) I saw a while ago, consisting in a buggy PC file that Mono provides. I fixed the problem in [this commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/f7f522d26cddd3ad310c9ea0202012ed23059d96), you can try upgrading your Mono then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same "version" of Cairo.Context to use it.

You can see Cairo.Context in your case like this

1. You are in 2.0 with Cairo.Context
2. You are in 4.0 with Cairo.Context
3. Cairo.Context 2.0 is compare with Cairo.Context 4.0
4. It's not the same because 2.0 != 4.0

It's the better way to illustrate why your code doesn't work.

The solution referenced in your post explain that and specify how you can fix the version to use in the aim to have the good version in all cases and avoid the issue.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I've gathered, and I vaguely understand what he's doing, but have no idea about how to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

As said by knocte, this situation corresponds exactly to a fixed bug in mono.

I encountered the same issues, and installing a newer version of mono fixed thoses. Since it's not yet integrated in the latest ubuntu to date (13.04), I found this link quite useful : http://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/

This allows you to install a newer mono without getting through the trouble of compiling it manually.